# Equivalence of different definitions for Directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to understand the equivalence of two different definitions of directional derivatives.

$$\nabla_v f(x)=\lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{f(x+hv)-f(x)}{h}$$

Here, $f$ is a scalar function and $v$ is a vector along which we compute the derivative. It is [mentioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Definition) that this definition is equivalent to $\nabla f(x). v$ if $f$ is Differentiable at $x$.

I think that $f(x+hv)$ should be treated as a function of $h$ , and then use techniques from single variable calculus to prove the equivalence. However, I am unable to proceed.

Comment: Hint: Define $g(h)=f(x+hv)$ and compute $g'(0)$ using two ways: By definition of derivative and using chain rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Define $g(h)=f(x+hv)$ and compute $g′(0)$ using two ways: By definition of derivative and using chain rule.

The first step follows from the definition.

The second one can be solved with the following idea:

Let $u=x+hv\in\Bbb{R}^n$ be, then $u_i=x_i+hv_i,1\leq i\leq n$.

Thus, 
$$\frac{d g}{dh}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_i}(u)\frac{d u_i}{dh}(h)$$

But $\dfrac{du_i}{dh}(0)=v_i$, and $\nabla f(u)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_1}(u),\ldots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_n}(u)\right)$, moreover $u=x$ when $h=0$, therefore
$$g'(0)=\frac{dg}{dh}(0)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_i}(x)v_i=\nabla f(x)\cdot v$$

Comment: I thought i had figured it out :( By the definition of differentiation, $g(0)=\nabla_v f(x) $. How does chain rule help here?

Comment: Look the extended answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the chain rule for this, but a working knowledge of what *differentiable* means. By definition, $f$ is *differentiable* at $x$ if there is a linear map $L=:df(x)$ such that 
$$f(x+X)-f(x)=df(x).X+o(|X|)\qquad(X\to 0)\ .$$
When $X:=h v$  this leads to
$$f(x+hv)-f(x)= df(x).(h\,v)+o(h)\qquad (h\to0)\ ,$$
so that
$$\lim_{h\to0}{f(x+h v)-f(x)\over h}=df(x).v=\nabla f(x)\cdot v\ .$$

Comment: This is a lot clearer.